# Why I cannot get state from Store with Mobx in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, store, mobx

Now I code below one which tries to get state set in Mobx Store.
However, I don't know why that state is "undefined".

Fortunately, I never get any error through this issue.

This is a component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View} from 'react-native';
import { Provider, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import RestaurantStore from '../Stores/RestaurantStore';
import GeneralScreenComponent 
        from'../Components/GeneralScreenComponent';

@observer
class Restaurant extends React.Component {
  render() {
   console.log(RestaurantStore.headerTitle);
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Provider store={RestaurantStore}>
       <GeneralScreenComponent
         headerTitle={RestaurantStore.headerTitle} />
     </Provider>
   </View>
  );
 }
}
```

And this is Store.

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class RestaurantStore {
 @observable headerTitle = '飲食';
}


export default RestaurantStore;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't instantiated your `RestaurantStore` store. Update your `RestaurantStore` module by revising your `export` line as follows:

```
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class RestaurantStore {
 @observable headerTitle = '飲食';
}

// Ensures that the RestaurantStore is instantiated whenever it's used in your application
export default new RestaurantStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

I have just changed

```
export default RestaurantStore;
```

To

```
export default new RestaurantStore();
```